# Why doesn't Python's .ravel() preserve decimal places in an array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

A section of my code builds square neighborhoods for each pixel in a 3D array, which are then flattened via `.ravel()`. My 3D array contains 3 values: 0, 0.5, and 1. However, when I call `.ravel()` I lose all the 0.5 entries, which are converted to either 0 or 1 (I don't know which way they get pushed). Why doesn't `.ravel()` preserve the decimal information and is there a way around it?

```
#the recon array has been initialized with a random distribution of values 0, 0.5, and 1
#recon_size and offset are also predefined, as well as the shape of each Neighborhood array
#I can provide the content for both comments above in an edit if so desired
counter1 = 0
for z in range(recon_size):
    for y in range(recon_size):                       
        for x in range(recon_size):
            xp = x + offset
            yp = y + offset
            zp = z + offset
            #Create a list for the neighborhood centered at this pixel      
            Neighborhood1[counter1,:] = recon_padded[zp,(yp-offset):(yp+offset+1), (xp-offset):(xp+offset+1)].ravel()
            Neighborhood2[counter1,:] = recon_padded[(zp-offset):(zp+offset+1), yp, (xp-offset):(xp+offset+1)].ravel()
            Neighborhood3[counter1,:] = recon_padded[(zp-offset):(zp+offset+1), (yp-offset):(yp+offset+1), xp].ravel()
            counter1 += 1
```

Comment: It does. You have some other problem. Maybe you have an array of integer dtype.

Comment: Show the code that first creates `Neighborhood1`, `Neighborhood2` and `Neighborhood3`.  These are probably created with an integer data type, so when you write `Neighborhood1[counter1,:] = ...`, the values on the right must be converted to integers to store them in `Neighborhood1`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, my neighborhood declarations needed a dtype flag. Thank you